# How are the downloadable assets accessed after being downloaded by using the background assets framework in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, background-assets-framework

How are the assets downloaded using background assets framework accessed by the app in SwiftUI?

I just need clarification on the question about accessing assets that are downloaded using background assets framework in SwiftUI.

Comment: In answer to your question, the manager will inform your [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundassets/badownloadmanager/3930940-delegate), calling [`download(_:finishedWithFileURL:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundassets/badownloadmanagerdelegate/4027485-download). You can use them in-place, or move to some other purgable space (e.g., your “caches” directory). See the docs and video on the [tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/background-assets-framework/info).